# Show or Hide Div if one Div has Value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, css

I know there are tons of examples on how to show or hide a div based on click or hover or some kind of user event. I'm looking for a java script sample or jquery sample that shows or hides a div based on weather the div has value. In other words. I am displaying a list of concerts in your area. If there are no concerts in your area another div should be displayed instead saying "there are no concerts in your area".

This needs to happen on page load. Without any user involvement.

Anyone ever used something like tis or a=can point me to a link that shows how to do this?

Thanks
Oceantrain

Comment: hm... hard to say without any markup code.  Could you post some code or a demo? maybe a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Assuming that the list of concerts is being generated by PHP/MySQL or similar... can you not just check the amount of concerts to output, then if 0, output the "no concerts in your area" string, or output a whole new div with that text and different class etc .

Comment: Asp.Net MVC. I do have the no concerts in your area div displaying. And no results show up, however, there is a div with a description being displayed as well. If list of concerts is empty, hide description div, show no concert div. Is what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of example to do this

Generally people use this to check/condition on value.

```
     if( $("this").val().length === 0 ) {
     $("this").hide()
```

Secondly

```
if( !$("this").val() ) { $("this").hide() }
```

With  you can use text() or html()...

Something like
`var text = jQuery("div").text();`

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    var $div = $("#div1");
    if(!$div.html().length)
        $div.hide();
});
```

If you would like to use a class selector, you can use the following code:

```
$(function(){

    var $div = $(".foo");

    $.each($div, function(i,v){ 
        var _$div = $(v);
        if(!_$div.html().length)
            _$div.hide();
    });
});
```

working demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tugberk/mAaDY/

Comment: @JosephMarikle time for me to go to bed I think :D thanks! fixed it.

Comment: you're welcome. :)  I think we all make mistakes like that (at least I know I have >_>)

Comment: I can't seem to get any of these to work. Does div1 have to be an ID? can it be a class? as in: $(function(){
    var $div = $(".concertbody");
    if(!$div.html().length)
        $div.hide();
});

Comment: @EB I cannot say that the above code will work for class selectors for sure. If there are multiple elements, then it will only check the first one. see my update.

Comment: Thanks Tugbert. I looked at your demo. It seems both Divs are still being displayed. Do I need to set a div as Display:none; or Hidden; First in order to show and hide 2 divs?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    var $div = $("#div1");
    if($.trim($div.html()).length == 0) {
        $div.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I created this prior to tug changing his answer but mine also has a trim function to make sure that all possible white-space is trimmed in the length check.

Comment: Hells yeah brotha, also I might be tired myself but doesn't your code need to have a length comparison since length doesn't return a boolean?

Comment: @DeviantSeev I believe he's relying on the fact that 0 evaluates to boolean false

Comment: it doesn't have to be. run this code: `if(100)alert("true");` and this `if(0)alert("false");`."

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
if($("#div1").is(":empty"))
$("#div1").css("display","none");
$("#div2").css("display","block");
});
```

That should be one way how to make it work. For sure you must put in some logic that decides what div will be displayed.